# How can I get part of a value from variable using REGEX extractor in JMeter?

Tags: regex, testing, jmeter

I have a request in JMeter and I want to get some values from the body that it returns to me.

Here is a part of the HTML body return:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__Code" id="__Code" value="53e9d02a-727s-4b13-9w6be-bsfq44a8221251" />
...
<input name="$CpfCnpj" type="text" value="26341646784" maxlength="14" id="CpfCnpj" autocomplete="Off" style="width:200px;" />
...
<a href='javascript:ExibirFilaItemPedido(5101709, false, false);'>198062084</a>
```

I want to get the 5101709 value.

I'm trying to get this value with REGEX Extractor

[image: JMeter]

But the value that I'm getting is "(5101709".

If I put the REGEX "[0-9]{7,}" the value that I get is the "8221251" and I don't want this one. I can't put the number 5101709 fixed, because this numbers can change. Someone knows how can I get only the numbers after the "("?

Comment: Try `[(]([0-9]{7,})` and `$1$` template ("modelo"). Or even `[(]([0-9]{7,}),`

Comment: Both worked! Can you put this as an answer for me to check it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
[(]([0-9]{7,})
```

and set the template to `$1$`.

The `[(]([0-9]{7,})` pattern matches a `(`, then matches *and captures* into Group 1 (that you access with `$1$`) seven or more digits.